# R apply odd behaviour with NA

Tags: r, apply

I have a correlation matrix between 2 sets of variables.
I want to find the variable B that has the max correlation with each of the As

```
> B = data.frame('B1' = c(3,3,5), 'B2' = c(2,7,8))
> A = data.frame('A1' = c(1,2,3), 'A2' = c(4,2,6))
> corr_matrix = cor(A,B)
> corr_matrix

          B1        B2
A1 0.8660254 0.9332565
A2 0.8660254 0.1555428
```

I run

```
> temp = apply(corr_matrix,1,which.max)
> temp
A1 A2 
2  1
> names(B)[temp]
[1] "B2" "B1"
```

And get a nice vector of what I need.  Heres the catch.  If my matrix looks like this

```
corr_matrix

           B1 B2        B3
A1         NA NA        NA
A2  0.3986434 NA 0.2807630
A3 -0.3568664 NA 0.6037172
A4  0.1974342 NA 0.6827092

apply(corr_matrix,1,which.max)

$A1
integer(0)

$A2
B1 
1 

$A3
B3 
3 

$A4
B3 
3
```

I get an odd nested structure which I don't particularly understand.  Can someone please explain what this structure is and why it comes out differently from the example above?

I mean I would be happy if it spat out

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
NA  1  3  3
```

Last of all, I can see the answer I want (NA,B1,B3,B3) but how do I get it out in a vector form?

I see many NA + apply threads but none of them seem to work for my purpose so I apologize if this is a duplicate of something that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correlation matrix:

```
corr_matrix <- as.matrix(read.table(text = "B1 B2        B3
                          A1         NA NA        NA
                          A2  0.3986434 NA 0.2807630
                          A3 -0.3568664 NA 0.6037172
                          A4  0.1974342 NA 0.6827092", header = TRUE, row.names = 1))
```

You can define a function to treat the cases where all values are `NA`:

```
temp <- apply(corr_matrix,1, function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else which.max(x))

temp
# A1 A2 A3 A4 
# NA  1  3  3 

names(B)[temp]
# [1] NA   "B1" "B3" "B3"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is really helpful.  Would you also be able to explain what the odd nested structure is and how I might deal with that should I come across it again?

Comment: @hjw `integer(0)` is an integer vector of length 0. For further information, have a look at Arun's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sven's solution is the way to go in general. But for this case, you can get away by changing the `mode` of your output list to `numeric`:

```
ll <- structure(list(A1 = integer(0), A2 = structure(1L, .Names = "B1"), 
      A3 = structure(3L, .Names = "B3"), A4 = structure(3L, .Names = "B3")), 
     .Names = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"))

mode(ll) <- "numeric"
ll
# A1 A2 A3 A4 
# NA  1  3  3
```